# Information on Duration or Start/End Time

Tags: user-behavior, web-app, info-visualisation, charts, edit

My question has split my team in the middle, so I'm here for more opinions. We have this Gantt Chart where you can extend/shrink tasks by hovering then dragging them from start/end. When this interaction starts, a tooltip appears with the information on the active edit.

Such as:

[image: Tooltips and Actions]

So our main issue is with the interaction from the start of the task. Should the tooltip show Duration as in the example, or should it show the relative Start Time? (That would mean the last to tooltips would be - 20 min / + 20 min)

Thank you in advance :)

Note: I'm trying to make it as small as possible, this is just one feature of the chart, the overall is a very crowded UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since time is such a core component of Gantt charts, including both the time and the offset might suit this use case best, in order to have both absolute clarity and relative perspective of the change.

Something like the following might work:

[image: Showing the previous time, proposed new time, and the offset]

This slightly larger tooltip is explicit about the previous time, new proposed time, and the offset, in a still fairly small tooltip.

Comment: +1 on the slightly larger tooltip. Since this is a transitory action, the size of the tooltip is of  little concern if the tradeoff is more clarity about the interaction and the outcome.